# Clojure Core function argument positions seem rather confusing. What's the logic behind it?

Tags: clojure, lisp, clojurescript, clojure-core

For me as, a new Clojurian, some core functions seem rather counter-intuitive and confusing when it comes to arguments order/position, here's an example:

```
> (nthrest (range 10) 5) 
=> (5 6 7 8 9)

> (take-last 5 (range 10)) 
=> (5 6 7 8 9)
```

*Perhaps there is some rule/logic behind it that I don't see yet?*

I refuse to believe that the Clojure core team made so many brilliant technical decisions and forgot about consistency in function naming/argument ordering.

Or should I just remember it as it is?

Thanks

---

Slightly offtopic:

`rand`&`rand-int` VS `random-sample` - another example where function naming seems inconsistent but that's a rather rarely used function so it's not a big deal.

Comment: You can find lots of discussion about this topic online, especially in the context of threading. For example [here](https://stuartsierra.com/2018/07/06/threading-with-style). [This here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/iyyNyWs53dc/-A0wq9O5N1IJ) is a classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some functions (especially functions that are "seq in, seq out"), the args are ordered so that one can use `partial` as follows:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [dozen      (range 12)
        odds-1     (filterv odd? dozen)
        filter-odd (partial filterv odd?)
        odds-2     (filter-odd dozen) ]
    (is= odds-1 odds-2
      [1 3 5 7 9 11])))
```

For other functions, Clojure often follows the ordering of "biggest-first", or "most-important-first" (usually these have the same result).  Thus, we see examples like:

```
(get <map> <key>)
(get <map> <key> <default-val>)
```

This also shows that any optional values must, by definition, be last (in order to use "rest" args).  This is common in most languages (e.g. Java).

---

For the record, I really dislike using partial functions, since they have user-defined names (at best) or are used inline (more common).  Consider this code:

```clj
  (let [dozen   (range 12)
        odds    (filterv odd? dozen)

        evens-1 (mapv (partial + 1) odds)
        evens-2 (mapv #(+ 1 %) odds)
        add-1   (fn [arg] (+ 1 arg))
        evens-3 (mapv add-1 odds)]

    (is= evens-1 evens-2 evens-3
      [2 4 6 8 10 12]))
```

---

### Also

I personally find it ***really annoying*** trying to parse out code using `partial` as with `evens-1`, especially for the case of user-defined functions, or even standard functions that are not as simple as `+`.

This is especially so if the `partial` is used with 2 or more args.

- For the 1-arg case, the function literal seen for `evens-2` is much more readable to me.
- If 2 or more args are present, ***please*** make a named function (either local, as shown for `evens-3`), or a regular `(defn some-fn ...)` global function.

Answer (score 7):

There is an FAQ on Clojure.org for this question: https://clojure.org/guides/faq#arg_order

> ### What are the rules of thumb for arg order in core functions?
>
> Primary collection operands come first. That way one can write → and its ilk, and their position is independent of whether or not they have variable arity parameters. There is a tradition of this in OO languages and Common Lisp `(slot-value, aref, elt)`.
>
> One way to think about sequences is that they are read from the left, and fed from the right:
>
> ```clj
> <- [1 2 3 4]
> ```
>
> Most of the sequence functions consume and produce sequences. So one way to visualize that is as a chain:
>
> ```clj
> map <- filter <- [1 2 3 4]
> ```
>
> and one way to think about many of the seq functions is that they are parameterized in some way:
>
> ```clj
> (map f) <- (filter pred) <- [1 2 3 4]
> ```
>
> So, sequence functions take their source(s) last, and any other parameters before them, and partial allows for direct parameterization as above. There is a tradition of this in functional languages and Lisps.
>
> Note that this is not the same as taking the primary operand last. Some sequence functions have more than one source (concat, interleave). When sequence functions are variadic, it is usually in their sources.
>
> Adapted from [comments by Rich Hickey](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/iyyNyWs53dc/Q_8BtjRthqgJ).

Answer (score 5):

Functions that work with seqs usually has the actual seq as last argument.
(map, filter, remote etc.)

Accessing and "changing" individual elements takes a collection as first element: conj, assoc, get, update

That way, you can use the `(->>)` macro with a collection consistenly,
as well as create transducers consistently.

Only rarely one has to resort to `(as->)` to change argument order. And if you have to do so, it might be an opportunity to check if your own functions follow that convention.

Comment: This is broadly correct, but it should be noted that the `nth` family of functions break this rule, taking a sequence first and an index last. I think this is because their argument order was borrowed from functions with the same name in other lisps, before Clojure had settled on its own style. Some argue that `nth` follows this rule because it takes a collection first, like `get`, and not a sequence, but I don't really buy this - you use it like a sequence.

Comment: Well. One would hope you are using nth on a vector or you’d pay linear access cost. I don’t think it breaks the convention.